# How to allocate the correct charge in Materials Studio

Tags: materials-studio

I tried to use the sorption module in materials studio to study the adsorption isotherm of carbon dioxide on FUA zeolite with a silicon aluminum ratio of 1:1. FUA zeolite has balanced its charge by adding 99 Na+. but I don't know how to allocate a certain amount of charge to each atom in the zeolite skeleton and carbon dioxide. Therefore, I automatically allocate it through the COMPASSIII force field. However, my final result shows that the zeolite skeleton carries 96 charges(In theory, the zeolite skeleton should not be charged), and the calculated carbon dioxide adsorption amount is also greater than the experimental value in the literature. Can you provide me with an answer? What should I do?[image][image]

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it has been more than 6 months, is there any update you can provide us? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Please let us know!